# Integration U-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble understanding how they go from $du = 3x^2$ to $dx = \frac{1}{3x^2} du$.

I've set $u$ to be $x^3$ and then $du$ is $3x^2 dx$.  Then $3x^2 dx$ becomes $3$.  Then I get a bit lost on how they get to $dx = \frac{1}{3x^2} du$.

[$x^3e^{x^4}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSs8O.png)

Comment: Divide both sides by $3x^2$.

Comment: I don't quite follow, which two sides?  x^3 and 3x^2?

Comment: $$\require{cancel}
du = 3x^2dx \ \leadsto \ \color{red}{\frac1{3x^2}}du = \color{red}{\frac1{3x^2}} 3x^2dx = \frac1{\cancel{3x^2}} \cancel{3x^2} dx = dx.$$

Comment: If you set $u$ equal to $3x^2$, then, they are *equal*.  If you differentiate both sides, since they were the same to begin with, they are *still* the same.  That means that $du = 3x^2\,dx$ is an equation on the level of any other equation.  So, you can divide both sides of that equation by $3x^2$, and both sides will still be equal, because you did the same thing to both of them.

Comment: @azif00 I can see how it works now, the only part i don't quite understand is why you use 1/3x^2 and it doesn't become du/3x^2?

Comment: @neilmh Well, $\dfrac1{3x^2}du$ and $\dfrac{du}{3x^2}$ are the same thing. That's what you mean?

Comment: @azif00 yes sorry, getting myself confused.  so writing it as 1/3x^2 du is just a clearer way of writing it than du/3x^2.

Comment: thanks for your help @azif00.  Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\int x^3e^{x^4}dx$$
Notice in U-Substitution method we want to eliminate all the $x$s and $dx$ instead have $u$s and $du$. so by substitution $u=x^4$ we achieve this purpose because:

$$u=x^4\quad\quad du=4x^3dx$$
Therefore $x^3dx=\frac14du$ (note that it was not necessary to extract $dx$ like you mentioned in your question):

$$\frac14\int e^u du=\frac14e^u+C$$
Since $u=x^4$ the integral is equal to $\frac14 e^{x^4}+C$.

Comment: Jalebe! Nice explanation Soheil. :)

Comment: @Miksaa mamnoon;) you're welcome!